# java frameworks complexity statistics

Tags: java, frameworks, code-complexity

It is extremely difficult to **illustrate the complexity of frameworks** (hibernate, spring, apache-commons, ...)

The only thing I could think of was to compare **the file sizes of the jar libraries** or even better, **the number of classes contained in the jar files**.

Of course this is not a mathematical sound proof of complexity. But at least it should make clear that some frameworks are lightweight compared to others.

Of course it would take quiet some time to calculate statistics. In an attempt to save time I was wondering if perhaps somebody did so already ?

### EDIT:

Yes, there are a lot of tools to calculate the complexity of individual methods and classes. But this question is about third party jar files.

Also please note that 40% of phrases in my original question stress the fact that everybody is well aware of the fact that complexity is hard to measure and that file size and nr of classes may indeed not be sufficient. So, it is not necessary to elaborate on this any further.

Comment: I don't think the size of a jar of the number of classes it includes can tell much about complexity of a software. What makes a software complex (or not) is for example amount of decisions and paths in the control flow that has to be taken to achieve a task. To get a closer idea start first with [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125898/tool-for-calculating-cyclomatic-complexity) you can find some tools for measuring cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: There are many possible metrics used to evaluate code, do some research to find out which ones matter to you. Cyclomatic complexity is for methods, not an overall framework. For that you'd need coupling, cohesion, etc stats.

Answer (score -1):

There are tools out there that can measure the complexity of code. However this is more of a psychological question as you cannot mathematically define the term 'complex code'. And obviously giving two random persons some piece of code will give you very different answers.

In general the issue with complexity arises from the fact that a human brain cannot process more than a certain number of lines of code simultaneously (actually functional pieces, but normal lines of code should be exactly that). The exact number of lines that one can hold and understand in memory at the same time of course varies based on many factors (including time of day, day of the week and status of your coffee machine) and therefore completely depends on the audience. However less number of lines of code that you have to keep in your 'internal memory register' for one task is better, therefore this should be the general factor when trying to determine the complexity of an API.

There is however a pitfall with this way of calculating complexity, as many APIs offer you a fast way of solving a problem (easy entry level), but this solution later turns out to cause several very complex coding decisions, that on overall makes your code very difficult to understand. In contrast other APIs require you to do a very complex setup that is hard to understand at first, but the rest of your code will be extremely easy because of that initial setup.

Therefore a good way of measuring API complexity is to define a task to solve by that API that is representative and big enough, and then measure the average amount of simultaneous lines of code one has to keep in mind to implement that task.
And once you're done, please publish the result in a scientific paper of your choice. ;)